# A very simple distributed client/server example?

Tags: concurrency

If I had a very simple service, which is done on a Server, how would I make this service scalable, as in, run over multiple servers? Is it using `register(mod,func,[args])`?

I am getting a little confused between spawning a process, creating a node and creating a new server.

How do you offload client activity onto new servers to spread the load?

Answer (score 3):

Spawning processes lets you achieve bigger granularity which utilizes efficiently multicore. It also gives you chance to implement async behaviour.

Creating node lets you distribute your system over many hosts. Nodes may see each other and communicate transparently.

If server is stateless enough you can just create couple server nodes and load balance traffic between them.

If server has some heavy computation you can map/reduce over it using couple server nodes.

I am not sure what you mean by this code snippet with register. Usually you do not register server end-points, but some kind of router which has knowledge about server nodes, location, load..

'Node' and 'process' come from Erlang world, but 'server' is a layer in your system. Any node can be designed to become server or it can generate client requests. Processes are spawned on nodes, local or remote. Processes may perform/implement server or client logic.

Answer (score 1):

follow this full [Erlang online free book](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content) and you will discover everything. You could jump straight to multiprocessing, Distribution and Client/Server systems